# Laravel 5.0 not work Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a web service like below.

```
Route::get('testingpost', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user_id;
    });
```

> Request URL xxxxxx.com/xx/testingpost?user_id=111
>
> OUTPUT null

As you can see, the request is not working. Does anyone know a solution to this?

P.S. The 'post' method doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you `dd($request)` for us?

Comment: yes already do it....

Comment: Can you also show us what dd($request) returns? @bizzwebsite

Answer (score 0):

Get query parameters using this way

```
$request->input('user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test this  in route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/testingpost?user_id=1`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('testingpost', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->get('user_id');
});
```

output :
`1`